# Calling Rails action from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the this `link_to` in my that calls the `update` action in my controller:

`<%= link_to((image_tag("lock_closed.svg", :class => "edit")), :controller => "sections", :action => "update",:id => section.id, :remote => true)  %>`

---

But I would really like to call the `update` action through some javascript with an ordinary image tag.

So something like:

`<%= image_tag("lock_closed.svg", :class => "edit")%>`

and:

```
$(".edit").click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass("update")){
    // call update action
    } else {
    //do something else 
    };
})
```

---

Is it possible to call an action this way? I've been finding a bit on using `GET` & `POST` or `Ajax` methods but I'm not sure how to utilise them to target a specific controller & action.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Send an Ajax call

```
$(".edit").click(function(){  
  if ($(this).hasClass("update")){     
    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "/sections/<%= section.id %>"
    });
  } else {
    //do something else 
  }; 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve the issue of `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`
on the ajax call we should send also the *`authenticity_token`*.

```
 $.ajax({
   url: '/sections',
   data: { authenticity_token: $('[name="csrf-token"]')[0].content, 
           id: <%= section.id %> },
   method: 'POST',
   success: function (res) {
     ....
  }
});
```